# CodeIgniter 4 - Multiple Databases Problem with .env file

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter 4.0.3. I've installed it using `composer` via:

`composer create-project codeigniter4/framework`

*Got one error after the composer project creation was finished (`Script bash admin/setup.sh handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error code 127` --- running on Windows 10), but quickly resolved it by editing the `composer.json` and removing the `bash admin/setup.sh` directive*

I've successfully followed up the [tutorial](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/tutorial/index.html) and after that, I decided to make some changes to make it more similar to my web-app requirements, such as adding multiple databases.

Starting with the documentation ([here](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/database/configuration.html) and [here](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/database/connecting.html)), I read that I have to modify my `.env` file. So, here was the original

```
# ORIGINAL .env
database.default.hostname = localhost
database.default.database = ci4
database.default.username = root
database.default.password =
database.default.DBDriver = MySQLi
```

And I wanted to do something like:

```
# MODIFIED .env
database.primary.hostname = localhost
database.primary.database = ci4primary
database.primary.username = root
database.primary.password =
database.primary.DBDriver = MySQLi

database.secondary.hostname = localhost
database.secondary.database = ci4secondary
database.secondary.username = root
database.secondary.password =
database.secondary.DBDriver = MySQLi
```

Next, in my Model I have called Database to connect via:

```
use Config\Database;

...

$dbPrimary   = Database::connect('primary');
$dbSecondary = Database::connect('secondary');
```

When I run the app, I get the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentException primary is not a valid database connection group
```

I don't know what else to do, I tried various edits of the `.env` file, tried debugging the `Config` class (which I think it does not load the `primary` nor the `secondary` subkeys --- nor do I have any idea on how to change the class to read them from my environment file).

Quick checklist:

- `env` file has been moved to `.env`
- both `ci4primary` and `ci4secondary` databases exist and have the proper tables with data
- database credentials are ok
- CI environment is set to development

Answer (score 2):

The database connection groups in the `.env` file must also exist in the `app/Config/Database.php` file. By default only the `default` and `tests` connection groups are defined.